# Send form data + image (resize and crop) with Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I try to send a simply form with data and upload photo resize and crop,
I use this code HTML

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="sujet">Sujet de l'article</label>
<input class="sujet" id="sujet"  name="sujet" type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Statut de l'article</label>
<select name="DropDownTimezone" id="statut" class="statut">
<option value="1">Valide</option>
<option value="2">En attente</option>
</select>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="texte">Message*</label>
<textarea id="texte" class="texte" rows="8" name="texte"></textarea>
</div>
<input name="__files[]" type="file" multiple />
<input type="submit" id="bouton"  class="bouton" value=" Add post " name="Addarticle" >
  </form>
```

I use this Jquery code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.bouton', function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 
var form = $('form').get(0);
var formData = new FormData(form);// get the form data

$("#bouton").attr('disabled','disabled');
$("#bouton").val('Traitement ...');
    $.ajax({
        url: "sendarticle.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
}
}); 
}); 
</script>
```

And this code for add data in database, but when i try i have no data in database

```
<?php
session_start();
include "./config.php";
error_reporting(0);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$titre = $_POST['titre'];
$texte = $_POST['texte'];
$image = $_POST['image'];
$image_g = $_POST['image_g'];
$validite = $_POST['validite'];

$query = "INSERT INTO weart_actu SET image_g ='$destination_thumbnail_save',image ='$destination_file_save',titre ='$titre', texte ='$texte', validite ='$validite', date='$date' ";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: Well, error reporting is disabled, I would start by enabling it, and see what it says. It might be something like: "$db is NULL", perhaps? Other variables also don't seem to be defined.

Comment: I have never seen this FormDatra https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData , learned somthing new today. Maybe your browser does not support it? IE < 10 or Opera < 12

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "sendarticle.php",
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false
}).done(function(data){
   you can do callback as you want
}).fail(function(err){
   console.log(err) 
})
```

php file upload:
http://www.w3school.com.cn/php/php_file_upload.asp